# python schedule multiple functions

Tags: python-3.x, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule and run 2 functions

func1 to run for a specific duration
func2 to run for a specific duration

```
time1 = 4:20
time2 = 6:20
duration1 = 1 hour
duration2 = 1 hour

def func1():
    print("func1") # random function

def func2():
    print("func2") # random function
```

I just gave an idea of the code, it would be a great help solving it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll **try** to fulfil your requirements...

So you'll need a code to run func1 at a specific time and till the specific duration then run func2 at a specific time and till the specific duration....

according to that I'll import `schedule` and `time`.

```
import schedule  
import time

# make sure the time is in correct format....If the time is 4:20, then you must enter 04:20...
time1 = input("When do you want to start func1 ? (format=00:00): ")

# 1 hour = 3600
# 1 hour, 15 mins = 4500
# 1 hour, 30 mins = 5400

# make sure the duration is only in seconds... for 1 hour you must enter 3600
duration1 = input("What will be the duration of func1 ? (format = only seconds): ")


# make sure the time is in correct format if the time is 6:20 then enter 06:20
time2 = input("when do you want to start func2 ? (format=00:00): ")

# make sure the duration is only in seconds... for 1 hour you must enter 3600
duration2 = input("what will be the duration of the func2? (format = only seconds): ")



def func1():
    # your func1
    print("func1") #example

    time.sleep(int(duration1))

def func2():
    #your func2
    print("func2") #example

    time.sleep(int(duration2))
    exit()


def looping():
    schedule.every().day.at(time2).do(func2)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


schedule.every().day.at(time1).do(func1)
while True:
    looping()
```

I tried to give my best according to your requirements, hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time.sleep()` function from `time` module if that's what you are looking for.